# Re-Link Xaml and Code Behind in Visual Studio Solution

Tags: c#, xaml, visual-studio-2017

I have XAML file say `SomePage.xaml`.

I was making a mistake by refactored it's code behind class from `SomePage` to `CardsPage` class.

Now XAML file doesn't link with the code behind anymore.

[image: Separate File]

How to link these files together again?

Comment: They are linked in the .csproj file, open that in a text editor and look for a pair that is linked and copy the example for the two files that aren't linked (it's just xml)

Comment: Thanks, I will try that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you open the project file that includes your CardsPage, you can link them back together again.

You should have 2 sections in there, one should be like this:

```
<Page Include="CardsPage.xaml">
  <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
  <SubType>Designer</SubType>
</Page>
```

The other section should look like this:

```
<Compile Include="CardsPage.xaml.cs">
  <DependentUpon>CardsPage.xaml</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
```

The DependentUpon is important, it will nest the file in the IDE below the xaml.
**Note**: In your screenshot, the CardsPage looks like it was renamed to CardsPage.cs, I would make sure that you rename it back to CardsPage.xaml.cs.

Hope that helps, I sadly don't know any other way than fiddling in the project file to make it work again.

Answer (score 3):

I have some problems when I refactor the code behind with the XAML(renaming for example) and I find a small extension to "relink" files together.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.FileNesting

It's easier than modifying the csproj and **less dangerous**.

See Example Below

**Step 1**
[image]

**Step 2**

[[image: [2]]

**Result**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Xamarin Forms, try editing your ".projitems" file located on the same directory of your .xaml files of your Xamarin project, there is the asociation between the .cs files and .xaml files like this

```
<Compile Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)MyPage.xaml.cs">
  <DependentUpon>MyPage.xaml</DependentUpon>
  <SubType>Code</SubType>
</Compile>


<ItemGroup>
 <EmbeddedResource Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)MyPage.xaml">
  <SubType>Designer</SubType>
   <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
 </EmbeddedResource>
</ItemGroup>

<Compile Update="C:\Projects\MyPage.xaml.cs">
  <DependentUpon>MyPage.xaml</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
```